# Handle asychronous in BackHandler react native and react navigation v.4

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

I have a screen that could back with hardwarebackpress and i want to execute an asynchronous dispatch useDispatch hooks before execute goBack() static method. But it will be pass (not execute). How can i do this?

this is some resume code may could clear this issue.

i have an action that dispatch with react hooks useDispatch:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', backButton); //listener for hardware back button

    //some code here.. 

    return () =>
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', backButton);
  }, [booked, rescheduleData, errorReschedule]);
```

and this is backButton method that have dispatch action

```
function backButton() {
    let time = timeSelected;
    let id =
      navigation.state.params.type === 'book'
        ? navigation.state.params.data.doctor_id
        : navigation.state.params.item.Doctor_Id;
    Alert.alert(
      'Peringatan',
      'Apakah anda yakin ingin keluar dari halaman pemesanan jadwal ?',
      [
        {
          text: 'Ya',
          onPress: () => {
            dispatch(
              clearFromBackButton({
                doctorId: id,
                start_time: time.jam[0],
                end_time: time.jam[1],
                is_reserved: false,
                is_selected: false,
              }),
            );
            navigation.goBack();
          },
        },
        {
          text: 'Tidak',
          style: 'cancel',
          onPress: () => console.log('cancel'),
        },
      ],
    );
    return true;
  }
```

and that backButton method is clearly fine and will execute dispatch action if i put it on some onPress button, but it not execute if i put it into backHandler/hardware back listener.